# Ruby on Rails Parse Library Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parse-platform, ruby-on-rails-4.2

https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client

PARSE Library for ROR

**Ruby 2.0
Rails 4.2.6**

My Query to get all followers from a user

```
@follow = client.query("Follow").tap do |q|
      q.eq("user",@user.pointer)
      q.include = "_User"
    end.get
```

Returns me correct data and

```
@follow.each do |p|
 p["following"] #contains users pointer
end
```

BUT displaying this returns

```
=p["following"].objects.first
```

**ERROR**

```
undefined method `objects' for #<Parse::Pointer:0x007fefa5506aa8>
```

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: What does `=p["following"].first` give you?

Comment: `undefined method "first" for #<Parse::Pointer:0x007fefa5ba5260>`

error

Comment: Can you show the code where you add the "Follow" relation?  I think that the real cause of this might be there.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill yes! it has a relation

Answer (score 1):

Parse::Pointer only has these accessors defined on it:

- attr_accessor :parse_object_id
- attr_accessor :class_name

and these methods:

- def make(class_name, object_id)
- def initialize(data)
- def pointer
- def eql?(other)
- def hash
- def new?
- def to_h(*_a)
- def to_json(*a)
- def get(client = nil)
- def to_s

and these aliases:

- alias id parse_object_id
- alias as_json to_h

There are no iterators / enumerators or anything like what you're trying to do; the Parse::Pointer is just a reference (pointer) to another parse object.

You CAN do something like this:

```
@follow.each do |p|
  following = p["following"]
  "Following: #{following.class_name} (#{following.id})"
end
```

And that will display all of the objects that are following.

If you need to access the details of the objects, you'll need to resolve them each as you process them.

Comment: But that method I used is already documented there. But not working. Just wanted to check whether I have implemented that wrong or something else. Anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: I didn't look at the documentation, I looked at the code.  Those members that I listed in the answer are copied from the code, and there are no others.  Which documentation are you looking at?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: Already mentioned in my questions
[Parse Ruby Client](https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client)